# How to restore deleted C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Python.sublime-package?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Now, Python is not in the list of all types of languages that can be used.

I reinstalled Sublime Text 3 times.
But, the problem is not solved:
[image]

Please help me to get back that file.

Comment: Reinstalling should put the file back; are you saying that you re-ran the installer but somehow all of the files were installed but that one? What steps did you take during the reinstall?

Comment: I would recommend `Preferences > Settings` and check your settings on the right; is there an entry for `ignored_packages` with `Python` listed?